# How to stop transition between slides in powerpoint?

Tags: onclick, ms-office, powerpoint, transition, presentation

Is there any way to stop transition between slides on click in powerpoint ?
I have a dropdown menu in presentation and I want slides to change just by clicking 
menu buttons.

Comment: In slide show setup, set the presentation to run in Kiosk mode. That will disable advance on click.  You'll have to provide your own navigation then, via code or action settings on slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all slides, select transitions none (Sorry I have a German Version: Übergänge ohne). When you want to program it look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251489(v=office.12).aspx)